# Manifest.plist file ipad swift playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, manifest, swift-playground

How do I access the manifest.plist file in the swift playgrounds app on my ipad? I have tried messing around with the playground but can't seem to find the file. I also read apples docs and it tells me that the file is located at the top of the .playgroundpage folder but I can't seem to find that folder in the app either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the Code Editor there should be an ellipsis (...). Tap on that and scroll down until you see Adavanced, then View Auxiliary Source Files. Navigate around until you find a folder ending in .playgroundpage, and the Manifest file should be in it.

You can share this list, but you can't edit it in Swift Playgrounds so consider sending the playground to a Mac running Xcode to open the full file.